# List all resources of a certain OntClass using Jena API

Tags: java, rdf, jena

How do I list all the resources that belong to a certain [OntClass](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html) in a Model?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the OntClass documentation, and answers that can readily be found in documentation should not be asked on StackOverflow (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372/225437).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all of the instances of an OntClass, you can use one of the aptly named [`OntClass.listInstances`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#listInstances%28%29).  It's described clearly in the javadoc.  In general, I'd suggest that if you're using an API, it's good practice to skim the javadoc of the class or interface that you're working with.  You don't need to memorize every bit of it, but you'll have some idea of what's available and know where to look when you need something.

#### Code Sample

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntResource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class ListInstancesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load the wine ontology.
        final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM );
        model.read( "http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/wine.rdf" );

        // Get the Merlot class.
        final OntClass merlot = model.getOntClass( "http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#Merlot" );

        // Print each of its instances.
        for ( final ExtendedIterator<? extends OntResource> merlots = merlot.listInstances(); merlots.hasNext(); ) {
            System.out.println( merlots.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#LongridgeMerlot
http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#GaryFarrellMerlot
```

Comment: OntClass basically refers to the Ontology which is delinked from the Model that contains the resources. The function does not take the Model as the argument. So how is it supposed to work? Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: @user592748 An OntClass is a resource, and holds a reference to a model, yes. OntClass#listInstances is querying the OntClass's model for triples of the type (?individual,rdf:type,this).  To use OntClass#listInstances, you do need a reference to the OntClass, of course.  I've added a code example.